# Read from serial port in many forms

Tags: c#, serial-port, invoke

i am developing an application for manage trafic of personnel. app has 1 main form to show who is going and 1 form tu register cards.
i don't have problem to read data from serial port. my problem is when from main form go to register form and use serial port and back to main form this error was happen:

**Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.**

my code is here :

```
void mySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (RFIDActive)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            RFIDSerial = sp.ReadLine();
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowID));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and :

```
private void ShowID(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Some Code to display personnel data
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to invoke here? Is ShowID registered by other events? Do you use ShowID's sender and e arguments?

Comment: No.I don't use sender and e args. I test it,not difference between use and don't use Invoke Method. but still my problem not solved when switch between other forms

Comment: The error speaks for itself.  Your trying to invoke a method against an invalid handle.  You need to verify that an `Invoke` is even required before you do one.

Comment: How can i handle it ? by IsInvokeRequire?

Answer (score 0):

try with this,

```
public delegate void GetData(string receivedData);

void mySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (RFIDActive)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            RFIDSerial = sp.ReadLine();
            this.Invoke(new GetData(ShowID),RFIDSerial);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and :

```
private void ShowID(string RFIDSerial)
{
   //Some Code to display personnel data
}
```

Hope it helps,

Greetings.